# How do I change my Git home folder?

Tags: git, bash, shell, github, home-directory

How do I change my git home folder? Currently my git folder is located in my %AppData% folder. I store my projects in my C:\Projects folder. I would like my git bash to start up in my C:\Projects folder and whenever I cd to my home directory (cd ~) I want it to navigate to C:\Projects.

Comment: ~ is your user root directory

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
cd /c/projects
```

EDIT:
if you want it to start up within this directory, then just do this in cmd(admin):

```
setx HOME "C:\Projects"
```

after this you need to restart git-bash.
To test variable enter this in git-bash:

```
echo $HOME
```

Comment: Tested `cd ~`, and it has navigated to C:\Projects as expected.

Comment: It worked well and it did exactly what is in the question. In my case it also changed the "options" setting, i.e. color, fonts, window size, etc., to a default setting, which wasn't really difficult to change again.